# Replacing Empty fields on latest record with good data based on other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe, and I am trying to fill in the Null values with values from other rows.

[image]

Building the dataframe:

```
   data = [{'PersonalID': 84062174,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': 'male',
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'Geoff',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': None,
  'Account': None,
  'Last Updated Date': '2021-06-22 0:00',
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': None,
  'CreatedDate': '2021-04-14 10:00',
  'Notes': None,
  'Home Phone': None,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7805554444,
  'Extension': 'x9999',
  'Email': 'ghawes@gmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 83471000,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': None,
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'Geoff',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': 'title',
  'Account': None,
  'Last Updated Date': None,
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': None,
  'CreatedDate': '2021-04-16 10:00',
  'Notes': 'Project: MY project',
  'Home Phone': 7778881234.0,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7805554444,
  'Extension': None,
  'Email': 'ghawes@gmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 83458399,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': None,
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'Geoff',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': None,
  'Account': 'third record',
  'Last Updated Date': None,
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': 'you',
  'CreatedDate': '2021-03-20 17:05',
  'Notes': 'Project: My Project2',
  'Home Phone': None,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7805554444,
  'Extension': None,
  'Email': 'ghawes@gmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 82290675,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': 'male',
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'trevor',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': 'title',
  'Account': None,
  'Last Updated Date': '2021-06-22 0:00',
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': None,
  'CreatedDate': '2021-02-10 21:47',
  'Notes': None,
  'Home Phone': None,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7806665555,
  'Extension': None,
  'Email': 'thawes@hotmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 82269976,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': None,
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'trevor',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': None,
  'Account': 'my Account',
  'Last Updated Date': None,
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': None,
  'CreatedDate': '2021-02-09 21:47',
  'Notes': 'Project: More about projects',
  'Home Phone': 8887774321.0,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7806665555,
  'Extension': 'X5555',
  'Email': 'thawes@hotmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 76166887,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': 'female',
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'Cathryn',
  'Last Name': 'Anderson',
  'Job Title': None,
  'Account': None,
  'Last Updated Date': '2021-02-12 0:00',
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': 'Beth',
  'CreatedDate': '2020-06-09 10:59',
  'Notes': None,
  'Home Phone': 9997774445.0,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Cell',
  'Mobile Phone': 7807770000,
  'Extension': None,
  'Email': 'canderson@gmail.com'}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Rows where First Name, Last Name, Email are the same, (acting as a key) I want the record with the latest CreatedDate to fill in any Null values with other rows where there was data.

The results I am looking for would look like the following:

[image]
To build the DF:

```
data = [{'PersonalID': 84062174,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': 'male',
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'Geoff',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': None,
  'Account': None,
  'Last Updated Date': '2021-06-22 0:00',
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': None,
  'CreatedDate': '2021-04-14 10:00',
  'Notes': None,
  'Home Phone': None,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7805554444,
  'Extension': 'x9999',
  'Email': 'ghawes@gmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 83471000,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': 'mlae',
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'Geoff',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': 'title',
  'Account': 'third record',
  'Last Updated Date': '2021-06-22 0:00',
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': 'you',
  'CreatedDate': '2021-04-16 10:00',
  'Notes': 'Project: MY project',
  'Home Phone': 7778881234.0,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7805554444,
  'Extension': 'x9999',
  'Email': 'ghawes@gmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 83458399,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': None,
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'Geoff',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': None,
  'Account': 'third record',
  'Last Updated Date': None,
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': 'you',
  'CreatedDate': '2021-03-20 17:05',
  'Notes': 'Project: My Project2',
  'Home Phone': None,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7805554444,
  'Extension': None,
  'Email': 'ghawes@gmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 82290675,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': 'male',
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'trevor',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': 'title',
  'Account': 'my Account',
  'Last Updated Date': '2021-06-22 0:00',
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': None,
  'CreatedDate': '2021-02-10 21:47',
  'Notes': 'Project: More about projects',
  'Home Phone': 8887774321.0,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7806665555,
  'Extension': 'X5555',
  'Email': 'thawes@hotmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 82269976,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': 'male',
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'trevor',
  'Last Name': 'Hawes',
  'Job Title': None,
  'Account': 'my Account',
  'Last Updated Date': None,
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': None,
  'CreatedDate': '2021-02-09 21:47',
  'Notes': 'Project: More about projects',
  'Home Phone': 8887774321.0,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Home',
  'Mobile Phone': 7806665555,
  'Extension': 'X5555',
  'Email': 'thawes@hotmail.com'},
 {'PersonalID': 76166887,
  'Community': None,
  'Gender': 'female',
  'Date of Birth': '0000-00-00',
  'Title': None,
  'First Name': 'Cathryn',
  'Last Name': 'Anderson',
  'Job Title': None,
  'Account': None,
  'Last Updated Date': '2021-02-12 0:00',
  'Exclude From Traffic': 'No',
  'Area Sales Manager': 'Beth',
  'CreatedDate': '2020-06-09 10:59',
  'Notes': None,
  'Home Phone': 9997774445.0,
  'Phone Type 1': 'Cell',
  'Mobile Phone': 7807770000,
  'Extension': None,
  'Email': 'canderson@gmail.com'}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I have tried to do group_bys on the First Name, Last_Name, and Email and getting those results and then updating back to the original data frame based on the PersonalID. That was not giving expected results.

I then tried to bfill and ffill, and got closer. But this is updating every row, and not just the latest CreatedDate row.

```
df = df.groupby(['First Name','Last Name','Email','Mobile Phone']).bfill().ffill()
```

A bit stumped on where to try next, or if I need to revisit one of the above two ideas. Any recommendations?

Comment: why does ghawes@gmail.com not have a gender of male for index 2 ?

Comment: That is kind of the point of this exercise. There are various levels of missing data and I am trying to pull the recent record and fill in as much of that row as possible given info provided in previous rows with a key

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, first create your composite key for grouping.

```
#ensure createDate is a datetime object

df['CreatedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreatedDate'])

df['key'] = df.groupby(['First Name', 
                       'Last Name', 'Email'])['CreatedDate'].transform('idxmax')
```

sort your dataframe by the created date in descending order.

```
df = df.sort_values('CreatedDate',ascending=False)
```

and finally apply the bfill, and ffill operation.

```
df1 = df.groupby('key').ffill().bfill()    

print(df1) # try an example with fewer values, hard to vlaidate with lots of columns.

   PersonalID  Community  Gender Date of Birth  Title  ...    Home Phone Phone Type 1 Mobile Phone Extension                Email
1    83471000        NaN    male    0000-00-00    NaN  ...  7.778881e+09         Home   7805554444     x9999     ghawes@gmail.com
0    84062174        NaN    male    0000-00-00    NaN  ...  7.778881e+09         Home   7805554444     x9999     ghawes@gmail.com
2    83458399        NaN    male    0000-00-00    NaN  ...  7.778881e+09         Home   7805554444     x9999     ghawes@gmail.com
3    82290675        NaN    male    0000-00-00    NaN  ...  8.887774e+09         Home   7806665555     X5555   thawes@hotmail.com
4    82269976        NaN    male    0000-00-00    NaN  ...  8.887774e+09         Home   7806665555     X5555   thawes@hotmail.com
5    76166887        NaN  female    0000-00-00    NaN  ...  9.997774e+09         Cell   7807770000       NaN  canderson@gmail.com
```